# R to_categorical for sequence labeling with Keras

Tags: r, keras, sequence, labeling

I have a dataframe defined as such
I am trying to create a sequence labeling input for a Deep Learning problem.
So I have tags for each of the Sentence elements, I create vectors of WordIndex for the sentence elements, pad them for 10 dimensions, do the same operation for the Tags of the sentence elements (create the TagIndex for the tags, pad them to 10 dimensions).
then I need to convert the TagIndices into a Categorical variable. That is when the error comes up. Any help would be great. Is this the right approach ?

```
SentenceID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Tokens = c("I","went","to","school","nobody","can","find","some","people","know","what","they","are","doing","now")
WordIndex = c(3,4,7,8,9,10,12,54,34,66,33,89,87,23,22)
TagIndex = c(1,3,2,4,1,3,4,1,2,4,3,4,2,3,4)

df = data.frame(SentenceID, Tokens, WordIndex, TagIndex)

lst <- split(df$WordIndex, f = df$SentenceID)

lstWord2 <- lapply(lst, function(x){
  if (length(x) < 10){
    x2 <- c(x, rep(0, 10 - length(x)))
  }
  return(x2)
})

lstTag <- split(df$TagIndex, f = df$SentenceID)

lstTag2 <- lapply(lstTag, function(x){
  if (length(x) < 10){
    x2 <- c(x, rep(0, 10 - length(x)))
  }
  return(x2)
})

is.vector(lstTag2)

y <- to_categorical(lstTag2, num_classes = NULL)
```

The Error that I get is this.

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\balak\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 22, in to_categorical
    y = np.array(y, dtype='int')
```

Comment: I assume it is because `lstTag2` is a list as it is returned from a `lapply` call

Comment: You can avoid doing this step entirely if you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss as it assume you give integer labels and it will handle conversion for you.

Comment: Nuric and Relasta, Thanks a lot.  Nuric, I will give it a try. and update if that solves the issue. Have you come across any R code that handles bi-lstm crf for sequence modeling. As you can imagine, I would like to use Keras to predict Tags for me, based on input sentences and associated tags

Answer (score 0):

I guess to_categorical function requires that the input is a matrix, doing this makes it work:

```
SentenceID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Tokens = c("I","went","to","school","nobody","can","find","some","people","know","what","they","are","doing","now")
WordIndex = c(3,4,7,8,9,10,12,54,34,66,33,89,87,23,22)
TagIndex = c(1,3,2,4,1,3,4,1,2,4,3,4,2,3,4)

df = data.frame(SentenceID, Tokens, WordIndex, TagIndex)

lst <- split(df$WordIndex, f = df$SentenceID)

lstWord2 <- lapply(lst, function(x){
  if (length(x) < 10){
    x2 <- c(x, rep(0, 10 - length(x)))
  }
  return(x2)
})

lstTag <- split(df$TagIndex, f = df$SentenceID)

lstTag2 <- lapply(lstTag, function(x){
  if (length(x) < 10){
    x2 <- c(x, rep(0, 10 - length(x)))
  }
  return(x2)
})


y <- to_categorical(as.matrix(lstTag2), num_classes = NULL)
```

I got this:

```
> y
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0

, , 5

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0     0
```